# Using K9 with Gmail?

Tags: email, k9-mail

I need/want to use K9 to check a gmail account. I have two factor auth set up so I'm using an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) to sign in, but it keeps getting rejected, and then I get this error in my Gmail inbox:

> Are you the one who tried signing in? Google will continue to block
>   sign-in attempts from the app you're using because it has known
>   security problems or is out of date. You can continue to use this app
>   by allowing access to less secure apps, but this may leave your
>   account vulnerable.

Is K9 actually insecure? Or is Google just being stubborn?

Note: what I really want is a way to check gmail without tying the gmail account to my phone -- I have two gmail accts that are tied to short-term employers. I do want to see email to those accts but I don't want either acct tied to my whole phone. Ideally I'd read all my email from my various accts in K9, but I'm open to an alternate fix that allows me to read gmail without connecting my whole phone to the acct.

Comment: I think that Google deems apps "insecure" if they try to directly authenticate with your username/password (including an app-specific password) instead of using OAuth. It looks like K-9 [is working on it](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/issues/655).

Comment: `Ideally I'd read all my email from my various accts in K9, but I'm open to an alternate fix that allows me to read gmail without connecting my whole phone to the acct.` if by "k9" you mean the k9 browser, and if k9 is not a must, why don't you use chrome? Or any other browser

Comment: @Abochur K-9 is an [email client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) as well.